# Laser and mirrors on a 4x4 grid

Tags: optimization

You are given an empty 4x4 grid. You can place some diagonal mirrors into the cells of the grid. You then fire a laser from some location outside of the grid. The laser travels in a straight line. When it hits a mirror it bounces off at a right angle and spins the mirror by 90 degrees. The same mirror can be hit and spun multiple times.

Consider the following example. We place 4 mirrors in the centre of the grid and fire the laser below the second column. It hits the mirrors like so:

[image]

The mirrors spin around and the laser continues hitting another 2 mirrors before exiting the grid. In total it had 6 mirror hits:

[image]

What is the most number of mirror hits you can obtain on a 4x4 grid?

Comment: Do the mirrors spin instantaneously? eg. Would there be a sliver of laser reflecting upwards from the top-left mirror and to the right of the top-right mirror?

Comment: First the laser bounces then the mirror spins. So it is not instant.

Comment: Note in the final configuration, the bottom two mirrors will be in their starting orientation.

Comment: Mirrors usually have one side reflection - does your mirror reflect on both sides? Do we choose the direction for reflection?

Comment: What is the importance of the grid? Can we place mirrors in any direction?

Comment: Think of these as double sided mirrors, so they reflect on both sides. The grid tells you where you can place the mirrors. The mirrors must be placed diagonally within a cell.

Comment: Isn't this just Langton's ants with possible empty cells.

Comment: oh right, it is too.

Comment: @WhatsUp Not quite Langton's ants. In this, turning right or left also depends on where the ant is coming from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Proving a solution to be optimal will require programmatically checking all possible mirror placements, let's go ahead and do that.

The results are in, and the winner is:

> This layout, which scores 49 hits!
>  [image: Mirror grid]

This optimal solution is essentially unique. Aside from reflections and rotations, the only other optimal solution is the inverse, which follows the same path in reverse and has as it's initial position the final position of the above solution with all mirrors rotated.

Comment: That's very cool, thank you! Interesting that not all cells are used. Also I was hoping we can get an infinite loop, but perhaps there is no space for that. That might be my next puzzle.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky An infinite loop is impossible on any finite grid. Every mirror involved in the loop will be hit an infinite number of times. Consider the left-most column containing such mirrors, and then the top-most mirror in that column. That mirror will deflect the laser to the top or left in one of its orientations, sending the laser out into space and breaking the loop.

Comment: That's a nice proof. Thanks!

Comment: What if we add one fixed (nonspinning) mirror to the grid, can we get infinite loop then? If not, how many fixed mirrors do we need?

Comment: @RossPresser My argument holds for all four corners, so you need at least four. You could of course have them arranged on the corners of a rectangle, with the laser going looping around in that rectangle. There is however no way to set it up without the laser gun being in the way, even with additional spinning mirrors. The reason is that everything is time-reversible. If you film it going through one of the loops, you could play that backwards repeatedly and it would still be a valid looped path. That path loops, so could never go back to the laser gun that supposedly started it.

Comment: @RossPresser Another way to think of it is this: You can setup a 4-mirror infinite loop but there's no way to get the laser *into* that loop.

Comment: I don't suppose your computer program also generates a gif animated figure of the laser moving through the grid and flipping the mirrors? :(

Comment: @Stef No, that will take a bit more effort. I could probably create an animation in Blender, but that may take a while as I have no prior experience with the software.

Comment: Since you have a computer program, what winner amounts do you get for other $n$? Maybe there is a formula for, and/or an oeis sequence correlating to, the answer to this nice question?

Comment: @FirstName 4x4 has just over 43 million possible grids. 5x5 has nearly 20 thousand times as many. Run time for 4x4 is under a minute. For 5x5, could be over a week.

Comment: tag optimization was not a bad choice then :-) just curious, did you try 3x3?

Comment: @FirstName Easy enough. Optimal solution for 3x3 has 18 hits. With the added condition that all cells must contain a mirror, optimal solutions have 17, 46, and 85 hits. Allowing exactly one vacant cell limits the search space enough that 5x5 is still feasible (~450 million grids). In that case optimal solutions have 18, 49, and 102 hits.

Comment: perfect, I was curious if, perhaps unexpectedly, some existing pattern would be revealed

Comment: I found another optimal solution where the laser starts on a non-edge column.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky It is the inverse of the solution I posted.

Comment: oh I see what you mean by inverse now (I thought it's inverse of the mirrors).

Comment: For 5x5 I found a solution that scores 120, where laser starts in top left. I believe this could be optimal. https://pastebin.com/sAxkCUXF

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky You beat me to it. I was going to expand my 5x5 search to three, maybe four vacant cells. I estimate the run-time for three to be less than an hour; for four, about two and a half hours. Full search not more than 72 hours.

Comment: Well it would be nice if you can confirm that it is indeed optimal. I can then make an OEIS sequence out of it. Meanwhile I will search for 6x6.

Comment: I wonder what the growth rate for n*n/hits is?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky For 5x5, I checked all arrangements with up to 5 vacant cells. Your solution, with 120 hits, is optimal. Not only that, but it is its own inverse. For 6x6, a limited search on grids with one vacant cell finds \\\//\|\\/\\\|\\\/\\|///\/\|.\\///|\\\/// with 185 hits.

Comment: @DanielMathias thank you for verifying the 5x5! For 6x6 I can get 219: https://pastebin.com/J0NgPvvf

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky New approach, faster results. Complete search on 5x5 in 30 seconds. A bit longer (60+ hours total CPU time) on 6x6: https://pastebin.com/90cKNvNc

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky 23 hours, 37 minutes into the first of three processes (the others completed in under 20 hours) and we have a new high score: https://pastebin.com/iHZqqMjS

Comment: @DanielMathias nice work. I ran 5 instances of my program and 4 of them found the same solution, so it could be optimal: https://pastebin.com/xBh5CBZ5

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky My search was exhaustive, 233 is the maximum. Optimization of the new code reduced the 5x5 run time from 30 seconds to just 7 seconds.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName In case you're still interested, we now have optimal solutions for 5x5 (120 hits) and 6x6 (233 hits)

Comment: @Daniel Mathias : sounds good!

Comment: Perhaps it is time to look at 7x7? Here is my best: https://pastebin.com/D2VGDVPi

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Yeah, I've been optimizing my code for that. Exhaustive search on 5x5 now completes in about four seconds, with the search on 6x6 estimated at ten hours. I'm going to try to get an estimate on 7x7 runtime this weekend, but I don't really expect it to be reasonable.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Now this is interesting: https://pastebin.com/nCa3m9ZJ

Comment: @DanielMathias wow that is fascinating! A simple pattern with so many gaps works so well. I am going to try looking for more such patterns.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Estimated total CPU time for exhaustive search on 7x7 grid: 50 years. (Single-thread, 3.2 GHz) That is not unreasonable for distributed computing; I was expecting at least double. For comparison: 5x5, 1.9 seconds; 6x6, about 5 hours.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky https://pastebin.com/fpY491aT (still at the extreme tip of a very large iceberg) and some data in a  [spreadsheet with chart.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s3SGxUxF7hvIwH4mDLMF5U-3xnmU3BQwVI9rhfNhOmw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but here is an animation showing Daniel Mathias's answer.

> [image]

Comment: I love this! Thank you for making it.